# How can I alternate the float of my content?

Tags: css

I want to create a layout for an itemised list of content like below:

[image: Layout drawing]

Each item is a container that has an image and block of text.

I have attempted to use `nth-child` and set different css float values based on if it is an odd or even child, but you can't set child properties using the nth-child selector.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="media-container ">
        <img src="img/image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="titles">
            <h2>Title #1</h2>
        </div>
        <p>lots of words</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="media-container ">
        <img src="img/image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="titles">
            <h2>Title #1</h2>
        </div>
        <p>lots of words</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="media-container ">
        <img src="img/image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="titles">
            <h2>Title #1</h2>
        </div>
        <p>lots of words</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(odd) {
    .media-container {
        float: left;
    }
    .text-container {
        float: right;
    }
}

.flex-container:nth-child(even) {
    .media-container {
        float: right;
    }
    .text-container {
        float: left;
    }
}

.media-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.media-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.text-container {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

What is the easiest/neatest solution for creating this layout using CSS?

Comment: I can include the code I wrote but it's very obviously wrong for the reasons described in my question. Shall I include it for arguments sake?

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt..but if it's just rows on top of rows (which it appears to be) then `nth-child` certainly **would** be an option.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've added my code now. When written I was hoping that I could use nth-child to see how that particular container should be arranged, and add style to the child elements from there. But that's not how nth-child works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

Use the `nth-child` on your "row" flex-containers and alternate the `flex-direction`.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.media-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.text-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="media-container ">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="titles">
      <h2>Title #1</h2>
    </div>
    <p>lots of words</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="media-container ">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200">
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="titles">
      <h2>Title #1</h2>
    </div>
    <p>lots of words</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I accepted this answer over the others because it's a neater solution, using less styling than the others.

Answer (score 1):

Take A Look At This:

```css
.item {
  width: 305px;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item .title {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background: crimson;
}


.item .img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #09f;
}

.item:nth-child(even) .img {
  float: right;
}
.item:nth-child(even) .title {
  float: left;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) .img {
  float: left;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) .title {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <div class='title'></div>
  <div class='img'></div>
</div>
<div class='item'>
  <div class='title'></div>
  <div class='img'></div>
</div>
<div class='item'>
  <div class='title'></div>
  <div class='img'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that it is display:inline-flex? If you change it to inline-block, I believe you'll get your intended display:

```
.flex-container {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4rcdqy4f/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Javascript `querySelectorAll()` [method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp). Then, loop through the list of your items and add the specific CSS property based on whether it is odd or even.